# Post to inherit custom category background image from parent

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms, custom-background

I have a custom field on a category where you can add an image. I have it as a background image to show on the category's archive page, like so:

archives.php

```
<body style="background:url('<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>')">
```

It uses the Categories Images plugin to achieve this.

Is there a way for the posts in this parent category to inherit this background image? something like $cat->parent_id?

Comment: So `example.com/category/parent` and `example.com/category/parent/child` should have the same background?

Comment: Exactly yeah, I would like the /child to inherit or reuse the image which is associated with the /parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to output the parent category ID and then style off of that.

```
<?php
function wpse_74737_category_top_parent_id($catid) {
    while ($catid) {
        $cat = get_category($catid);
        $catid = $cat -> category_parent;
        $catParent = $cat -> cat_ID;
    }
    return $catParent;
}
```

And then call this in your `body` class: `<?php echo wpse_74737_category_top_parent_id( $cat->term_id ); ?>`

Comment: Hi developdaly this seems great! I don't think im calling it correctly in the single.php file though:  <body id="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($catParent); ?>">

Comment: Use `<?php echo wpse_74737_category_top_parent_id(); ?>` in `single.php`.

Comment: Hmm can't get this to work, I have tried to print out the output of this fucntion but it comes up with nothing. What should this be outputting? something like http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Virus_IQ1.jpg?

Comment: No, you should be getting the ID of the parent category. I forgot to mention that you need to provide the ID of the current category. So something like, `<?php echo wpse_74737_category_top_parent_id( $cat->term_id ); ?>`.

Comment: hey Developdaly I still need to fiddle with it but if you post the comment above as an answer ill gladly tick it.